# How can I filter dropdown values from another dropdown in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I am unable to filter the dropdown in WPF form like in c# form..

I created a list for my scenario dropdown and used it as items source in `LoadUserControl()` method as shown below.

```
  public class FilterListItem
  {
    public string Filter { get; set; }
  }

  public LoadUserControl()
  {
  InitializeComponent();
  List<FilterListItem> FilterList = new List<FilterListItem>();
  FilterList.Add(new FilterListItem() { Filter = "Make" });
  FilterList.Add(new FilterListItem() { Filter = "Model" });
  FilterList.Add(new FilterListItem() { Filter = "Year" });
  myscenario.ItemsSource= FilterList;
  myscenario.SelectedItem= "Model";
  }
```

Here's the code that i have for Script dropdown to filter as per the selection from scenarios dropdown.

```
private void myscenario_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {

 if (myscenarios.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Model")
    {
     Scriptlist.Add(script1);
     Scriptlist.Add(script2);
     break;
    }
 else if (myscenarios.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Make")
    {
     Scriptlist.Add(script3);
     Scriptlist.Add(script4);
     break;
    }

else
    {
     Scenariolist.Add(sc5);
     Scenariolist.Add(sc6);
    }
 }
```

When i execute the script, the UI is only going to default value which is model and whenever i select other value from dropdown, it still shows the selected item as "Model".

Also, When i debug for the value of the selected item from scenarios dropdown with the messagebox, i get this message as below.

```
**MessageBox.Show(myscenarios.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

//I get 'Filterlistitem' in message box instead of the selected item that i just selected.**

All i need is to filter the script dropdown as per the selection of the user in scenario dropdown like i mentioned above.

FYI, i didn't put the xaml UI just to make the question simpler.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

seleniumlover

Comment: If you remove the myscenario_SelectionChanged event handler can you change the selected item?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are using `List<T>` as the `ItemsSource` of your dropdown control which does not update the UI when the list changes. Use [ObservableCollections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) to notify the UI when the collection changes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm very new to WPF. Can you explain how to do the above problem with ObservableCollections to notify the UI when the collection changes?

Comment: Instead of a `List<T>` use `ObservableCollection<T>`.